# error with sql select

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a Java-code:

```
String searchPerson = "select * from persons where surname like ? and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= ?";
//connect to DB
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(searchPerson);
statement.setString(1,"%"+ surname + "%");
statement.setInt(2, age);
ResultSet resultPerson = statement.executeQuery();
//..code
```

Then I have SQLException:

```
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''
```

How to right? Help.

Thanks!

Comment: did you manually check your sql statement in your database?

Comment: @ZerO no, I never checked

Comment: so check this first. if the request does not work in your database, you know that something is incorrect with your request syntax

Comment: @ZerO yes, I have incorrect request, but i don't see mistakes

Comment: I am not that familiar with sql requests. But somebody else can surely help you with this. Now that we know that the problem is the request structure

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL try changing the line

```
"select * from persons where surname like ? and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= ?";
```

to this:

```
"select * from persons where surname like '?' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= ?";
```

The key is to add the first parameter between two apostrophes (')

The current SQL command is:

```
SELECT * FROM persons where surname like Name
```

But for SQL it should be acceptable in this format:

```
SELECT * FROM persons where surname like 'Name'
```

Comment: after test code, I have error with `String searchPerson = "select * from persons where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= 18" `

Comment: I am not that experienced in Java, but I suspect the error is coming from that if you select * (everything) from a table, it is giving you an array of results, not a string. To test this you could perhaps modify your query like this:    `select surname from persons where surname like '?' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= ? LIMIT 0,1`. If this works fine, then you should assign the results of the query to an array.

Comment: @user3629171 just try to save it in List na when u call select * from its giving more then one reciod.

Comment: @Alex as u using resultset i dont think so there will be prob with more then one record prob is something else can u post the stacktrace. ?

Comment: @Alex @Krishna I have error with `String searchPerson = "select * from persons where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) <= 18"` and the ERROR `you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''`. And ResultSet consist all users, who satisfy the query.

Comment: @user3629171 what u giving as dateofbirth?

Comment: @Krishna column with type DATE (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: @user3629171 then u have to use inner Query for get that all records?

Comment: @Krishna yes. I wanna select all users, for example, who grater than 18 years old

Comment: @user3629171 and what datatype u have given into the database?

Comment: @user3629171 okey wait min :)

Comment: @user3629171 try to take first static value try this 
SELECT * FROM tabledate WHERE surname = ? and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'1991-05-18',CURDATE()) >= 18;